# Intrinsic dot_product slower than a*a+b*b+c*c?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, gfortran, dot-product

Recently I tested the runtime difference of explicit summation and intrinsic functions to calculate a dot product. Surprisingly the naïve **explicit writing was faster**.

```pascal
  program test

  real*8 , dimension(3) :: idmat
  real*8 :: dummy(3)

  idmat=0
  dummy=0

  do i=1,3

      idmat(i)=1

  enddo

  do j=1,10**10

  !   dummy(mod(j,3)+1)=dot_product(idmat,idmat)
      dummy(mod(j,3)+1)=idmat(1)*idmat(1)+idmat(2)*idmat(2)+idmat(3)*idmat(3)

  enddo

  print*, dummy

  end program test
```

## Here is what confuses me:

### 1. No -O3 Optimization

If I use: `gfortran test.f90 -o test ; time ./test`

I find a runtime of **6,297s** using the function `dot_product` (commented above) and **4,486s** using the manual explicit writing.
How does that make sense?

### 2. Including -O3 Optimization

If I use: `gfortran test.f90 -O3 -o test ; time ./test`

I find a runtime of **1,808s** and **1,803s** respectively. So both are actually of the same speed.

### 3. What I actually expect

...is the intrinsic function to be faster, as it could:

1. compute the 3 products in parallel
2. add the 3 products

where the explicit form has to sequentially:

1. compute product 1
2. compute product 2
3. compute product 3
4. add the 3 products

Do I have to create a **new parallel dot_product** function to be faster? Or is there an *additional* option for the gfortran compiler which I don't know?

Please note: I read across the internet about SIMD, auto-vectorization  and parallelisation in modern Fortran. Although I learned something my question wasn't answered anywhere.

Comment: You didn't specify the way you measured the 'runtime'. Did you measure including write and program start? I think, a bit of O3 compiler would optimize the dot_product out of the `j` loop and maybe it is even clever enough to remove the entire loop. In the later case you nearly only measure the write and program start etc.

Comment: @albert Maybe I don't understand entirely what you mean. Measured meant to me this number: 

    ./test  3,27s user 0,00s system 99% cpu **3,286** total

Comment: This indeed what I meant, you don't measure the time of the dot-product but the total program execution time , so also programs startup and write statements. This might looks sensible but, especially for such small programs does not give relevant information. Also disk interaction / screen interaction (write) is going on which also is dependent on other processes running and whether or not things can be cached etc. I think that when you would reduce the loop to e.g. 1000 iterations you might get the same results.

Comment: Are you sure about the number of times the loop is executed (seen the O3 remark before) as 10\*\*10 is larger than the number that fits in a 32-bit integer with gfortran 6.4.0 I get at the 10**10 `Error: Arithmetic overflow at (1)` and no program.

Comment: The times make indeed more sense for 10**9. But the compilers I tried do not optimize out the loop. And the the other parts of the program are quite negligible.

Comment: @albert. It's true today when I parallelized the dot product I got this Error: Arithmetic overflow at (1). I don't know why it worked yesterday. Note: If I run it @ 1000 Iterations the runtime is about 1ms << 1s.

Anyway when I used omp to parallelize today the runtime actually exploded. I.E. only adding the option: **-fopenmp** increased the runtime from **1 second to minutes**. (So it is probably pretty inefficient)

Many Thanks to both you.

Comment: @VladimirF The optimization was just a guess, I've seen compilers (I think it was CDC for C) in the far past that did optimize out loops, but in that case there was no print statement either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense even looking at the non-optimized numbers. The optimized numbers are the same, so everything is fine.

*"...is the intrinsic function to be faster, as it could: compute the 3 products in parallel"*

There will be nothing done in parallel unless you enable specific parallel optimizations. These optimizations will be as easy to do for the loop as for the intrinsic and often even much easier for the loop.

Well, at least for the normal sense of *parallel* using threads or similar. What can be done in parallel is to use the vector instructions and to schedule the instructions to overlap in the CPU pipeline. That can be done by the optimizing compiler and is likely done for both versions when you use `-O3`. You should not expect this to happen when no optimizations are enabled.

The use of the "parallel" instructions ([SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD)) can be sometimes improved by using compiler directives like `!$omp simd` or `!$DEC VECTOR`.

*"Do I have to create a new parallel dot_product function to be faster?"*

Yes, normally you do. For example using OpenMP. Or you could:

*"Or is there an additional option for the gfortran compiler which i don't know?"*

Yes, the automatic parallelization https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/AutoParInGCC , for example `-floop-parallelize-all -ftree-parallelize-loops=4`

Note that it will not make those individual multiplications in parallel, it will make the `i` loop parallel.